# Слово "удивленный" в словосочетании "удивленный вид" – причастие или отглагольное прилагательное?

Tags: прилагательные, причастия, части-речи

Согласно [этому источнику](https://shareslide.ru/russkiy-yazyk/prezentatsiya-otglagolnye-prilagatelnoe-ih-otlichie-ot) (16-й слайд), так как есть приставка, то причастие.

> В причастии может быть приставка... Если хотя бы один признак у слова имеется, то это причастие

Согласно [другому источнику](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/test/otlichie-otglagolnyh-prilagatelnyh-ot-prichastiy) (упражнение 7), это прилагательное

> Чем является слово "удивлённый" в словосочетании "удивлённый вид"? – (отглагольным) прилагательным (правильно!)

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться!

Comment: Вид же не удивили, поэтому прилагательное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Удивленный вид"** - это прилагательное, возникшее из причастия ( произошел переход из одной части речи в другую, это продуктивный способ словообразования). Если бы это было причастием, мы бы могли совершить глагольную замену: *вид, который удивили.* Звучит совсем не по-русски.

---

Приведу пример, где слово **"удивленный"** будет причастием: *удивленный мальчик* (мальчик, которого удивили/кто-то удивил).

Answer (score 1):

```
   Быстрый ответ: ни то ни другое.

   В сочетании "удивленный вид" — прилагательное, но 
   не отглагольное (оно образовано не от глагола). 
   Слово не может быть причастием, так как словарю: 
   удивить (кого?), одуш. предмет.
```

1. ***Удивленный вид*** — прилагательное. Вид, выражающий **удивление**.

Большой толковый словарь

**УДИВЛЁННЫЙ**, -ая, -ое. **Выражающий** удивление. У. взгляд. У-ое лицо. У-ые глаза. // **Вызванный** удивлением. У-ое молчание. У. вздох. У-ая радость. Удивлённо, нареч. У. улыбнуться. У. смотреть на кого-л.

2. **О причастиях**

**УДИВИТЬ**, -влю, -вишь; **удивлённый**; -лён, -лена, -лено; св. кого. **Вызвать удивление** **в ком-л.**, поразить необычайностью чего-л. Сильно у. кого-л. У. своими стихами. У. родителей. У. поступком. Удивлять, -яю, -яешь; нсв. У. пением, поступком.

Глагол **переходный**, поэтому причастия обычно имеют **зависимые слова:** удивленный чем-то, сильно удивленный.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**  (об источниках)

1.На слайде 16 дана другая **информация.**  Там речь идет о прилагательных (одна Н), образованных **от ГЛАГОЛОВ**  (например, *сушить — сушенный, красить — крашеный*), которые при наличии приставки становятся **причастиями** (две НН): *высушенный, покрашенный*. Это правило 4-х признаков для выбора Н и НН.

2. Слово ***удивленный*** с приставкой ***У*** может быть причастием или прилагательным.

**Удивленный вид** — прилагательное. Это слово образуется не от глагола, а путем **ПЕРЕХОДА** из причастия в прилагательное (**морфолого-синтаксический** способ образования).

**Удивленный** (такими словами) мальчик — причастие.

Answer (score 0):

Удивление - удивленный, прилагательное.

Удивлять - удивленный, причастие.

В общем, нашёл следующее. Краткие прилагательные могут иметь столько Н, сколько Н было в полном, а причастия только одну Н. И как я понял нужна форма отличная от начальной мужской.

Удивленный - удивлена, одна Н значит это причастие. И в прилагательном поменялось бы ударение вроде удИвленна.

Однако, прилагательные с приставкой таки [есть](https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/n-i-nn-v-kratkih-prilagatelnyh#:%7E:text=%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0,%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5).):

Начитанная - начитана(прич.) - начитан(муж род) - начитанна(прил ж род)

Почтенный - почтенен(прил муж род) - почтенна (прил ж род)

Comment: Приставки усиливают глагольность.

Comment: @oleedd но изумл корень, карл... я, конечно, мало понимаю грамматику русского языка, но не до такой же степени.

Comment: При чём здесь "изумительный"? Здесь нет значения приставки "из". Должны быть связанные по смыслу слова поменьше, чтобы корень был меньше.

Comment: выйти из ума. Словарь Ушакова: ИЗУМЛЕ'НИЕ, я, мн. нет, ср. (книжн.). Крайнее удивление. С изумлением всматривался я в знакомое лицо: так изменила его болезнь. Не могу прийти в себя от изумления. [Первонач. лишение ума, умопомрачение.]
Да на вики увидел крайний синоним. Там удивленный - причастие и все.

Comment: Сейчас это уже не ощущается (связь с "ум"). Из ума человек точно не выходит, это о ярости. Тогда "ум" можно считать этимологическим корнем, тогда как стандартный (смысловой) — "изумл".

Comment: @oleedd именно так, но смысла искать какой-то иной корень кроме этимологического отсутствует, семантические корни это как химеры, наляпано че-то, почему, на кой - не разберешь. Дело в том, что семантический язык - это антиязык, так как его нормы устанавливает не здравый смысл, не логос, а группа "специалистов", с определенной целью, либо просто потому что так карта легла. Для меня,это как учится считать, но порядок счета устанавливается неким правилом написанным левой ногой. Вот есть слова мужчина и женщина, а им начинают приписывать значение искусственной гендерной концепции, и не только им.

Comment: И далее мы получаем, что слово не теряет, а замыливает первоначальное, истинное значение, чтобы угодить чьим-то влажным интересам, продвигающим трансгуманизм. Или вот, слова Родина и Отечество - ведь я так и не получил ответа на данный вопрос, а почему? Потому что в голове у людей такая каша, что уже роли Матери от Отца отличить не в состоянии, зато все стараются качать свои "права", не потому что зачем, а потому что научили в школе качать права. Или вот слово Субъект и Объект - ты знаешь, какой смысл в них вложен? А ведь язык, отражает то, какая пластинка играет в голове языкового субъекта.

Comment: Значение слова, семантический корень, это хрень которую придумали в 1920 году, без неё люди как то жили, без указания как надо воспринимать слова, как реагировать на значение слова ведь, как-то создавали язык, как-то развивали разум. Но в итоге ты получаешь не язык, а рекламную акцию нового продукта, слово не смысл, а знак - товарный знак, продвигающий определенный продукт, являющийся одновременно его лицом. Вот и вся философия современности, постмодерна. Смыслов нет, кроме тех, которые в тренде.
У слова смысл, помимо современно распиаренного - значения слова. Есть еще смысл причины.

Comment: причина слова - отражает Имя какого-то реального процесса, название парадокса, связанного с его пониманием и восприятием, а значение - это как знак на дороге, что захотели, то и сдизайнерили. Причина основа критического мышления, построения причинно следственных связей. Знак - для формирования реакции для чего-то или реакции от чего-то. Формирование реакций у живого объекта, животного, это дрессура. Знаковая система языка необходима для дрессуры. Вот, например, ты видел это откровенное видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_2F6Nbwbrs

Comment: Русский язык хорош тем, что у него есть два вида слов - греко-славянские смысловые корни и англицизмы-латинизмы - семантические конструкции. Такого по сути нет ни в одном другом языке, потому что в других языках нельзя органично вписать термин из другой языковой структуры. А в русском правила словообразования русского, логика, просто съедает химерное значение. Вот слово авторка - ну бредово звучит, а еще как я писал, можно сделать тогда форму авторища - женскую превосходную. В русском есть юмор. В русском есть фишки, слово, по сути не слово, а уже фраза. В русском нет плохих и хороших слов

Comment: в русском есть слова красивые и не красивые - уроды, слова со смыслом и бессмысленные - термины. А про видео, попробуй перевести все, что она сказала на инглиш. Это не представляется возможным. Тебе придется опираться на мир вещей, а не на мир слов, а значит, смысл будет ускользать и ты перейдешь на семантику.

Comment: Ого, сколько написано. Правило: Однокоренные слова — это слова разных частей речи, которые объединяет **смысловой** корень.

Comment: Да, остапа понесло. Слово смысл в русском языке отражает как значение, так и то, что является причиной или что-то являющееся следствие. То есть переводя на английский,  смысл это и meaning(содержание), significance(значение), sense(ощущение от, эмоция), так и причина cause(причина, первоначальный мотив, задумка, умысел, замысел),idea(замысел), essence(первооснова)

Comment: Смысловой корень, он как этимологический, так и морфемный-семантический. Вот есть слова: убийство - ты скажешь корень убий, но корень бить, просто приставка у дает деструктивное значение - убрать, ударить, умысел, ушла. Приставка определяет значение, корень связан не с семантикой, а с этимологией. Слово в русском - это фраза, а не морфема. корень+семантические элементы конструкции, поэтому авторка, директорка и тд будут звучать смешно, что ты не делай. Язык отторгает насилие. Слова уроды. Авторища, директорища.

Comment: Приставки и предлоги, суть одно и тоже. В английском основная нагрузка на предлогах, в русском на приставках, суффиксах и тд. - формах слова.

Comment: Корни в русском языке не такие глубокие, так сложилось, и так лучше, потому что носитель должен замечать связь и без этимологического словаря. А самый глубокий можно назвать "пракорень" или "надкорень". Или же, что красиво, "древний корень".

Comment: @oleedd древний корень - не тавтология). Не, не так важно кто что должен, точнее это совсем не важно, бесполезная информация, вопрос в том, почему должен. Насчет глубины - я бы поспорил. И глубина, не обязательно временной отрезок. Потому что время - это не линия, не только линия.